# Extract of an ebook with full table of contents

Tags: bookdown

I currently have a full ebook (=ebook) written in bookdown with a large table of content.

I am about to restrict the access to this ebook after registration on a website. I would like to have an extract of this ebook (= extract book) accessible before registration though.

In this extract book, I would like to restrict the access to some chapters while keeping the entire TOC of the ebook on the left side.

In TOC, the reader would see something like:

Chapter 5

- 5.1 Section 5.1
- 5.2 Section 5.2
- 5.3 Section 5.3

Once the reader click on '5.2 Section 5.2' in the TOC, I would like him to see:

Chapter 5

"This chapter is only accessible after FREE registration".

I have searched a lot to make the title of specific (sub)sections invisible somehow (like setting the colour to white) but with no success. Anyone has a work around to suggest?

Thanks,

Maxime